# Setting page numbering on Word 

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, microsoft-office-2007, page-numbers

I have a word document. The first four pages are title and index. After that, the “Chapter 1” starts. I want page numbers to begin from the “Chapter 1” onwards only. The first 4 pages should not have any page number.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

This is possible, but first you have to "separate your table of contents and your chapters section by inserting a "break".  Put your cursor where you want a break (in this case, at the end of your table of contents, at the *bottom* of your 4th page), then go to the "Page Layout" tab, and click "Breaks" in the Page Setup section of the ribbon interface.  Choose the "Next page" section break option, and it will create a new section.
[image]

Then put your cursor at the top of the 5th page, the first page of the 2nd section of your document.  Go to the 'Insert' tab, then click on 'Page Number' in the 'Header and Footer' Section.  When you click it, it shows a drop down menu, and you can click 'Format Page Numbers...

[image]

In the dialog box that pops up:

[image]

Choose "Start at:" and pick your first page number - if you want your chapter page to say '1' page on at the top, then put in a '1'.  If you want it to say page '5', then put in a '5'...

Hope that helps!