# Cannot suppress page numbers in MS Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, paging

In the question [Setting page numbering on Word](https://superuser.com/questions/198712/setting-page-numbering-on-word) the questioner wants page numbers to show up only on the 5th page onwards, beginning with page number 1.  The accepted answer shows how to do this, namely by splitting the text by inserting a section break, then insert page numbers at that point, with numbers set to start at Page 1.

That question pertains to Word 2007, and I presume that it works as described, but I have Word 2010, and it does not work that way.  I insert a section break at page 9, and set page numbers to begin at 1 (earlier text is all ToC, Dedication, Foreword, Copyright info, and title page).  But that previous section also has page numbers, starting at 1.  I am able to format the page numbers in section 1 separately from section 2, but I can't suppress them in section 1 -- or I can't find an option for this.

Is there a way?  Or will I have to grit my teeth and accept "i, ii, iii, iv" for page numbers in section 1?

Comment: Edit the footer of the first section and remove the page field?

Comment: @DavidPostill, I tried that, but it deletes all page numbers from all sections.

Comment: [Number pages differently in different sections](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-pages-differently-in-different-sections-1ba9047e-4534-460f-8003-12a81bb527f3#bm1) "To use different numbering in different sections of your document, **you need to make sure that the sections are not linked.**"

Answer (score 0):

Reference [10 steps to setting up page numbering in Word sections](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-steps-to-setting-up-page-numbering-in-word-sections/)

> **6: Break the connection**
>
> As you just learned in the previous step, page numbering isn't
>   autonomous in sections by default. You must break the connection
>   between the two sections. To break the connection between the first
>   and second sections, click Link To Previous on the Header And Footer
>   toolbar. (If you closed the header in the last step, reopen it and
>   Word will display the Header And Footer toolbar.) In Word 2007 and
>   2010, click the Design context tab | Link To Previous (in the
>   Navigation group).
>
> ...
>
> **8: Disable page numbering for the title page**
>
> Chapter 1 begins with the page number 1 -- that's good. But the first
>   two pages of the document, the title page and table of contents page,
>   still display page numbers 1 and 2, respectively. Fortunately, you can
>   easily inhibit this legacy numbering as follows:
>
> 1. Go to the first page and open the header (if necessary).
> 2. Highlight the page number.
> 3. Press Delete.